# How to import a very large file into R (separate by comma)

Tags: r, read.csv, readr

I have an `xls` file that contains over a million rows of data.  Everything is in one column and separated by commas. It takes a very long time for Excel to open it, and all I need is two pieces of information - customer ID and transaction amount.

My approach is to import the file into R (separate by comma), then extract the two columns I need. The problem is that everything is still in one column after importing. I have tried `read.csv(file, sep = ",")` and `read_csv(file, col_names = T)` from `readr`. None worked. However, I saved the first five rows as another `xls` file for testing, and it imports fine (correctly separated) without any issue.

I also tried `cSplit` to split the imported dataset by comma, but I got the `Error: C stack usage 14478558 is too close to the limit`. I guess it's due to the file size. I'm sorry that I can't provide a replicable example, but the data looks like below with one million rows:

```
  customer_id,type,note_number,amount,company
  1,cc,abc,5,A
  2,dc,bcd,7,B
  3,cc,cde,10,C
```

**Edit**

Thanks to @akrun for suggesting `data.table::fread(file)`,  the warning message from the function made me realize that some fields contain `,` inside `""` in the source file. What makes it more tricky to import and separate is that some have several `""`. For example, someone's name can show up as `""Joh, Dep""` instead of `"Joh Dep"`.

Also, as @RonakShah suggested, I created a [sample test file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iBSvz-lTRa5QXFgCfVYzAqlJNigwsQg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you tried `data.table::fread(file)`

Comment: You can also take a look at the [`vroom`](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom) package

Comment: @akrun, thank you for the suggestion! I tried `data.table::fread(file, quote = "", sep = ",") and got a `Warning message: Stopped early on line 6. Expected 12 fields but found 14. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=.` So I added `fill=TRUE`. Then I got a similar warning message `Stopped early on line 9686. Expected 14 fields but found 15`.  Now I know the problem is that some lines have commas within quotes. For example, `1,cc,"ab,c",5,A`. Is there a way to ignore the commas within quotes?

Comment: Remove `quote = ""` from your `fread` call?

Comment: @pseudospin I get two additional warnings besides the stop error if I remove it: `Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted, try quote="" to avoid this warning` and `Detected 1 column names but the data has 9 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 8 extra default column names at the end`.

Comment: Is the file available somewhere to test our answer.

Comment: @RonakShah I created a [sample test file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iBSvz-lTRa5QXFgCfVYzAqlJNigwsQg/view?usp=sharing) in .txt, because I'm working on a different PC and importing xls gives me the embedded nul in string error. I think the main issue is the `,` inside `""`.